# If $A=B^2 = C^2$, do $B$ and $C$ commute?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and a bounded positive operator $A$.

Let $B,C$ two operators such that $B^2 = A = C^2$.
Do $B$ and $C$ commute  ?

Comment: Even there are counter-examples on $H$ with $\dim H = 2$. For instance, two appropriately chosen reflections $B$ and $C$ will satisfy $B^2 = C^2 = \mathrm{id}$ but $BC \neq CB$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a concrete example: $H=\mathbb C^2$, $A=I_2$,
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ \ C=\begin{bmatrix}0&i\\-i&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$